# Escape double quote in sybase

Tags: escaping, sybase, sap-ase

I am running a query on a database to retrieve records in a CSV (with quotes) format:

`"Data","More data","some "funny" data with quotes","more"`.

Now when this is parsed, there is an obvious problem with this bit:

`...,"some "funny" data with quotes",...`

Is there a way to "escape" these quotes in sybase to save me post-processing?

Comment: I'm not quite getting what you are trying to do.  I don't see the difference between the data you have, and the parsed result.  A single quote is the escape for Sybase

Answer (score 1):

--after you execute this sentence:
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

--you will be able to execute:
select count(*) from "/table/name"
go

Answer (score 0):

if it's just double-quote you want to select in a literal string, use single quote as the string's delimiter.

Try select '"' and you'll see